# How to access same propety from different class without type casting in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 class which have same number of properties with same name. I want to access property without type casting.

```
class A : NSObject {
    var amount : Int = 10
}

class B : NSObject {
    var amount : Int = 20
}
```

Now I want to double the value of amount property like this

```
main() {
    let classA : A()
    print(doubleValue(classA))

    let classB : B()
    print(doubleValue(classB))
}

func doubleValue(myClass:AnyObject) -> Int {
    return myClass.amount * 2
}
```

Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Comment: Create a protocol with an `amount` property and make the classes conform to the protocol.

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what protocol are used for. Let us call this new protocol `Amountable` and add the `amount` property.

```
protocol Amountable {
    var amount: Int { get set }
}
```

If you want to provide a default implementation for `doubleValue()` you can event use protocol extension as follows:

```
extension Amountable {
    mutating func doubleValue() {
        self.amount *= 2
    }
}
```

Finally, let your classes conform to the protocol:

```
class ClassA: Amountable {
    // Implementation of classA here
}

class ClassB: Amountable {
    // Implementation of classB here
}

objectA = ClassA()
objectA.doubleValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@objc` you don't need protocol. This code is working in Swift5.

```
class A: NSObject {
    @objc var amount: Int = 10
}

class B: NSObject {
    @objc var amount: Int = 20
}

main() {
    let classA = A()
    print(doubleValue(classA))

    let classB = B()
    print(doubleValue(classB))
}

func doubleValue(myClass: AnyObject) -> Int {
    let amount = myClass.value(forKey: "amount") as! Int
    return amount * 2
}
```